# Graph disconnected issue in Keras

Tags: keras

[Architecture I want to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdyQy.png)

I wish to implement this architecture with Keras functional API. I am new to this and here is my code for now (which gets stuck at concatenating inputs).

```
# Arbitrary dimension for all embeddings
embedding_dim = 10

# Quarter hour of the day embedding
input_quarter_hour = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_quarter_hour = Embedding(metadata['n_quarter_hours'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_quarter_hour)
embed_quarter_hour = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_quarter_hour)

# Day of the week embedding
input_day_of_week = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_day_of_week = Embedding(metadata['n_days_per_week'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_day_of_week)
embed_day_of_week = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_day_of_week)

# Week of the year embedding
input_week_of_year = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_week_of_year = Embedding(metadata['n_weeks_per_year'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_week_of_year)
embed_week_of_year = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_week_of_year)

# Client ID embedding
input_client_ids = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_client_ids = Embedding(metadata['n_client_ids'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_client_ids)
embed_client_ids = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_client_ids)

# Taxi ID embedding
input_taxi_ids = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_taxi_ids = Embedding(metadata['n_taxi_ids'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_taxi_ids)
embed_taxi_ids = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_taxi_ids)

# Taxi stand ID embedding
input_stand_ids = Input(shape=(1,))
embed_stand_ids = Embedding(metadata['n_stand_ids'], embedding_dim, input_length=1)(input_stand_ids)
embed_stand_ids = Reshape((embedding_dim,))(embed_stand_ids)

# GPS coordinates (5 first lat/long and 5 latest lat/long, therefore 20 values)

coords_in = Input(shape=(20,))
coords_out = Dense(1, input_dim=20, init='normal')(coords_in)

#model = Sequential()

concatenated = concatenate([
            embed_quarter_hour,
            embed_day_of_week,
            embed_week_of_year,
            embed_client_ids,
            embed_taxi_ids,
            embed_stand_ids,
            coords_out
        ])
out = Dense(500, activation='relu')(concatenated)

out = Dense(len(clusters),activation='softmax',name='output_layer')(out)

cast_clusters = K.cast_to_floatx(clusters)
def destination(probabilities):
    return tf.matmul(probabilities, cast_clusters)

out = Activation(destination)(out)

model = Model(concatenated,out)
```

I am getting this error :

> Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_64:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "input_64".
>   The following previous layers were accessed without issue: [].

I am guessing the problem stems from the size of my tensors... But I don't now how to debug this kind of code.

Answer (score -1):

You should pass a list of all inputs to the model when creating a Keras `Model` instance. The variable `concatenated` that you are using in your code does not contain the inputs but instead contains the outputs of certain layers. Moreover, you should not concatenate your inputs but simply use a list.

The following code should work:

```
inputs = [
    input_quarter_hour,
    input_day_of_week,
    input_week_of_year,
    input_client_ids,
    input_taxi_ids,
    input_stand_ids,
    coords_in
]
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
```